# If statement not checking condition on first run

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode

just a little problem. My app stores some login info using NSUserDefaluts and users an IF statement to check if the file exist, if so it load second view, if not go to login screen.

Once the user enters Name, email etc they press go button which saves the details and takes to second view however the user has to press the go button twice before the app takes them to the second screen. I think the IF statement is not finding the saved details on the first run and therefore the button needs to be pressed a second time.

How can I over come this as it will be very frustrating for the user. I have included my code below. An explanation with code would be great appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender {

NSString *tempStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserName"];

  if (tempStr == nil || [tempStr isEqualToString:@""]) {

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:Name.text forKey:@"UserName"];
    [prefs synchronize];


    ClubSearchViewController *CSearch = [[ClubSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClubSearchViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:CSearch animated:YES];


  }
  else {
     SearchMenu *SMenu = [[SearchMenu alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchMenu" bundle:nil];
     [self presentModalViewController:SMenu animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend putting in some `NSLog()` statements to see what is going on in your code.  What you have written seems like it should work, so it is possible the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Or just step through it in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The code has to go in one of the two paths and present something, if it's not coming up on the first press that means it's not hitting that code.  Set a breakpoint to make sure it is.

The if statement should really be:

`if ( tempStr.length == 0 )`

Since you can pass messages to nil you get zero back if the string is empty or nil.  It's a bit simpler and takes less work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ran the debugger and it shows tempStr out of scope, prefs out of scope, CSearch out of scope and SMenu out of scope. What does out of scope mean?@raj2raaz @Caleb